# How to add login URL to button in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add the login URL to on-tap button in flutter without using launch method.I want the URL to open inside my flutter web app.It should not open other tab in web.How should I do that.

Comment: The url_launcher package you are using the launch() function of provides an optional parameter to open the page in web view. You can do the following : launch('https://www.google.com',forceWebView: true,enableJavaScript: true);    This will open the page in your app itself instead of external browser

Comment: new TextSpan(
                  text: 'but this is',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                  recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      launch(
                          'https://example.com',
                          forceWebView: true,
                          enableJavaScript: true);
                    },
                ), even if I do that its opening in a different tab . It is the flutter web application    ,we are doing it should open in same web page/same tab.